# How to use the terms we devise in an article?

Tags: style

In an article I defined a term which may not correspond to its general meaning. I devised the term "context" in order to describe an algorithm on the source of a Web page:

> After introducing some anchors, the user specifies the range of the nodes which are affected by a single anchor or a group of anchors. We call this range of nodes “context”.

In the other parts of the article like the following sentence, how should I refer to this term? should I always put it in quotations? can I use plural of it as it is in the sentence?

> The input of the algorithm is the DOM tree of the webpage, the list of anchors and the contexts created by the user.

In general, what are the guidelines for using such terms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option I would find clear is,

> We refer to this range of nodes with the term *context* through this article.

You then don't necessarily need to emphasize or mark the term subsequently.